# Vectors multiplication

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

If we have in a given vector space that the zero vector is a $2\times 1$ vector ($2$ rows and $1$ column) which is $\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}$.

To verify if this zero vector is in the set, we need to prove that $0.u=0$.

In this case we are multiplying a $2\times 1$ matrix ( the zero vector) by another $2\times 1$ vector in the vector space.

How could we obtain the result such that $u$ is defined to be $(a;a+1)$ ( one column and two rows)?

What I mean is that we can not multiply two matrices only if the number of columns of the first one is equal to the number of rows of the second one.

Comment: I think you mean $``$we can multiple$"$ instead of $` `$we cannot multiple$"$, right?

Comment: no you are adding

Comment: To verify whether or not the zero vector is in the set, the operation is addition and not multiplication.

Comment: Ohh okay I forgot that o.u=o where 0 is a scalar

Comment: Yes use unless instead of only. I did a mistake

Comment: @DanielKamand If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operations defined on a vector space are

1-vectors sum: $\vec v+ \vec w$

2-vector product by scalars: $ a\cdot \vec w $

The only request is that the vector soace is closed with respect to this two operations. Thus zero vectors needs to be in the vector space to guarantee the existence of the ordinary algebraic operations.

IE

$$\vec v+(-\vec v)=\vec 0$$

$$0 \vec v = \vec 0$$

Answer (score 0):

I assume $v.u=0$ should say, that the scalar product of the vector u and v should be $0$. So if $$
u=\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\u_2\\\vdots\\u_n\end{pmatrix}\text{ and 
}v=\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\\vdots\\v_n\end{pmatrix}
$$
then
$$
v.u = u_1v_1+u_2v_2+\ldots+u_nv_n=\sum_{k=1}^nu_kv_k,
$$ 
which is a number and can be equal $0$.

If my assumption is wrong, then you have to check the definition of $v.u$.

Comment: Ah when they tell us that 0.u must be equal to 0 for a set to be a vector space, they mean the dot product and multiplication?

Comment: And not* multiplication

Comment: I don't know what the definition of $v.u$ is. You should check that yourself. But somewhere I already have seen, that $v.u$ is also used for the dot product.